# How could be lazy loaded on demand a module at runtime in an Angular app?

Tags: angular, typescript

In the AppModule `RouterModule.forRoot(routes)` I have a condition to load either a module A, or a module B, depending on a browser cookie.

If the module A is loaded, the cookie can be updated and the AppModule should load now module B.

I can do that by reloading the app with `window.location.reload()`. However, I do not want to reload the page. How can I achieve that?

PS: I'm asking for version 8 of Angular

Comment: You can add `CanActivate` guard to the route and use `router.navigate()` inside it